# Find unique words from an array of anagrams using Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, anagram

I know how to do it without `Map`. It seems more logical to use `Map` for this task but I can't seem to implement it. Is this even possible?

So far I tied this:

```
function aclean(arr) {
  let result = [];
  let unique = new Map();

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let sorted = arr[i].toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");

    /*if (unique.add(sorted)) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }*/
  }

  return result;
}

let array = ["nap", "teachers", "cheaters", "PAN", "ear", "era", "hectares"];

console.log(aclean(array));
```

The result should be: `nap,teachers,ear` or `PAN,cheaters,era`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over your array using `.forEach()`, and check at each iteration whether or not your `Map` has a key of the sorted word, if it doesn't, then you set the sorted word as the key, and the word associated with the word as the value. You can then return an array of your map's `.values()` to get your result:

```js
function aclean(arr) {
  let unique = new Map();

  arr.forEach(word => {
    let sorted = word.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
    if(!unique.has(sorted)) {
      unique.set(sorted, word);
    }    
  });

  return [...unique.values()];
}

let array = ["nap", "teachers", "cheaters", "PAN", "ear", "era", "hectares"];
console.log(aclean(array));
```

Comment: If you don't care about the order, then simply `Map(a.map(w => [sorted, w]))`

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with the normalized (lower case, sorted) strings and return a filtered result.

```js
function aclean(array) {
    let unique = new Set();

    return array.filter(s => {
        let sorted = s.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
        if (!unique.has(sorted)) {
            unique.add(sorted);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

let array = ["nap", "teachers", "cheaters", "PAN", "ear", "era", "hectares"];

console.log(aclean(array));
```

Comment: In this case, I need a solution exactly with Map, but Your answer is so great too! Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 2):

I think `Set` is prefect for this case. You can do it in following steps.

- First make a helper function which sorts to the strings.
- Then create a unique array of sorted strings using `Set` and `map()`
- Then `map()` that array again to the value in original array which is anagram of the sorted string.

```js
const sort = str => str.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')
const aclean = arr => [... new Set(arr.map(sort))].map(x => arr.find(a => sort(a) === x)) 

let array = ["nap", "teachers", "cheaters", "PAN", "ear", "era", "hectares"];

console.log(aclean(array));
```

Comment: I need a solution exactly with Map. But Your solution works and You explain it very well. It deserves at least an upvote. Thank You!